# grep using a python (loop) variable and a string in a shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell

**Context:**
I have an internal Linux command, let's say "signals", which will give output whatever the signals placed for that day by oozie.

For example:

```
$signals | grep -i empty
*/user/oozie/coordinator/signals/2017/10/12/oltp1/_insurance_transaction_empty*
*/user/oozie/coordinator/signals/2017/10/12/oltp2/_loan_transaction_empty*

$signals | grep -i maxid
*/user/oozie/coordinator/signals/2017/10/12/oltp1/_insurance_transaction_maxid*
*/user/oozie/coordinator/signals/2017/10/12/oltp1/_loan_transaction_maxid*
```

I am writing a python script which runs every day and will grep for "empty" and "maxid" signals per *oltp* and send an email.

Let's say there are empty signal for oltp1 and maxid signal for oltp2. It will send an email with all oltps and signals.

I have a configfile which has all oltps in 1 column:

```
oltp1
oltp2
soltp
doltp
```

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import commands
import os

config_file="/home/xxx/config_file"
for var in confil_file:
    var=var.strip()
    print " checking with OLTP:"+var
    empty_cnt_loan=commands.getoutput("signals | grep -i empty | grep -i $var | wc -l")
    maxid_cnt_loan=commands.getoutput("signals | grep -i maxid | grep -i $var| wc -l")
    print empty_cnt_loan
```

attempts:
tried with $var

```
ERROR: grep: write error:Broken Pipe
```

tried with %var
empty_cnt_loan has value 0, where when i run the command in linux box, its has 2 value.

I tried subprocess, but since I am new I couldn't figure out how to use it.. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `var` isn't evaluated: try `commands.getoutput("signals | grep -i maxid | grep -i {} | wc -l".format(var))`

Comment: Thanks, but i got an error :(

`Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>",line 1,in <module>
ValueError: zero length field name in format`

Answer (score 0):

Running a complex Bash pipeline to do things which are trivial in Python is an antipattern.  Just run `signals` once and loop over the output in Python.

Assuming [Python 3.6+](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run),

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from subprocess import run, PIPE

with open("/home/xxx/config_file") as config:
    vars = [line.strip() for line in config.readlines()]
empty_cnt_loan = {x: 0 for x in vars}
maxid_cnt_loan = {x: 0 for x in vars}
p = run(['signals'], stdout=PIPE, check=True, universal_newlines=True)
for line in p.stdout.split('\n'):
    line = line.lower()
    for var in vars:
        if var in line:
            if 'maxid' in line:
                maxid_cnt_loan[var] += 1
            if 'empty' in line:
                empty_cnt_loan[var] += 1
```

As an aside, `grep` has an option `-c` to count the number of matches; but you really almost never need `grep` (or Awk, or `sed`, or `cut`, or a number of other standard utilities) when you have Python.